# Unit test doesn't cover code at all (Karma)

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a component:

```
export class StopwatchComponent implements OnInit {
  hours = '00';
  minutes = '00';
  seconds = '00';
  isPaused = true;
  isStarted = true;
  num = 0;
  @ViewChild('waitBtn', {read: ElementRef}) waitBtn: ElementRef;

  stopTimer() {
    (this.hours = '00'), (this.minutes = '00'), (this.seconds = '00');
    this.num = 0;
    this.timerService.stop();
    this.isStarted = true;
    this.isPaused = true;
    this.timer.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And wrote some tests for `stopTimer()` function but when I run test with coverage they don't cover it at all, and don't broke either
Here's my code:

```
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should create all parameters`, () => {          //works
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StopwatchComponent);
    const header = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(header.hours).toEqual('00');
    expect(header.minutes).toEqual('00');
    expect(header.seconds).toEqual('00');
    expect(header.isPaused).toEqual(true);
    expect(header.isStarted).toEqual(true);
    expect(header.num).toEqual(0);
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#waitBtn'));
  });

 it('should call stopTimer', () => {          //don't
    const mockSpyStopTimer = spyOn(component, 'stopTimer');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.stopTimer();
    expect(component.hours).toEqual('00');
    expect(component.minutes).toEqual('00');
    expect(component.seconds).toEqual('00');
    expect(component.num).toEqual(0);
    expect(component.isStarted).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.isPaused).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mockSpyStopTimer).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Is there any reason why your method doesn't actually _change_ any variables from their existing values?

Comment: Yeah, I have other functions in this component which change those variables and `stopTime()` should put it back to default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's not covering is because when you `spyOn` a method, you lose its implementation details and you just get an "API" where you can see whether it was called or not. To not lose the implementation details, use `.and.callThrough()`.

```
it('should call stopTimer', () => { 
    // now every time stopTimer is called, we have its original implementation details         
    const mockSpyStopTimer = spyOn(component, 'stopTimer').and.callThrough(); // change this line
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.stopTimer();
    expect(component.hours).toEqual('00');
    expect(component.minutes).toEqual('00');
    expect(component.seconds).toEqual('00');
    expect(component.num).toEqual(0);
    expect(component.isStarted).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.isPaused).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mockSpyStopTimer).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```